# Loading Vertex Shader Error

Tags: opengl

I am attempting to learn OpenGL 2.0 and I am trying to draw a triangle onto the screen.
When I try to load the vertex shader, it won't compile Here is my code(I am aware that my code is incomplete, I am just running it periodically to make sure I don't get too deep with errors):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLUT/glut.h>

 int init_resoureces(void){

GLint compile_ok = GL_FALSE, link_ok = GL_FALSE;
GLuint vs = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
const char *vs_source =
    "#version 120\n"
    "attribute vec2 coord2d;"
    "void main(void) {"
    "gl_position = vec4(coord2d, 0.0, 1.0);"
    "}";
glShaderSource(vs, 1, &vs_source, NULL);
glCompileShader(vs);
glGetShaderiv(vs, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &compile_ok);
if (0 == compile_ok){
    fprintf(stderr, "Error in the vertex shader\n");
    return 0;

}

return 1;
 }

void onDisplay(){

//fill in later

}

void free_resources(){


   }

  GLfloat triangle_vertices[] = {
   0.0, 0.8,
  -0.8, -0.8,
  0.8, -0.8

};

 int main(int argc,  char * argv[])
{

glutInit(&argc, argv);

glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);
glutInitWindowSize(640, 480);
glutCreateWindow("My First Triangle");

GLenum glew_status = glewInit();
if (glew_status != GLEW_OK){

    fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", glewGetErrorString(glew_status));
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

if (1 == init_resoureces()) {
    glutDisplayFunc(onDisplay);
    glutMainLoop();
}


free_resources();
return EXIT_SUCCESS;


 }
```

The program quits and says there is an error in the vertex shader (as it should with the if statement detecting compiling errors). I can't find the error in my shader, though.

Does someone know what I'm doing incorrectly?

If it matters, I am using Xcode and OS X 10.8

Thanks!

Comment: call [`glGetShaderInfoLog`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetShaderInfoLog.xml) to see the compile errors.

Comment: Among other things, it looks like you capitalized `gl_Position` incorrectly.

Comment: Thanks Ben, the tutorial I am following along with capitalizes it incorrectly I guess. I changed it and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OpenGL Shader Language, GLSL, is case-sensitive.

Make sure you capitalize `gl_Position` correctly.